# Why is this function not differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Why is the function

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\\\
0,&(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

not differentiable at $(0,0)$?

By setting $x=0$ or $y=0$ I would get  $f_x(0,0)=0$, $f_y(0,0)=-2$ and when I look at the 3-D Surface plot, $f(x,y)$ looks quite "normal". I gaze already hours on it and cannot identify the problem.

Obviously the partial derivates exist, but are not continuous, but I cannot see where.

Is there an analytic way, I can obtain the result from? How can I come to the conclusion, without gazing at the curve?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using theorems about the relationship between differentiability and properties of partial derivatives, let's just go back to the definition of differentiability:

A function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if and only if there is a linear function $L(x,y)=cx+dy+e$ such that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}{f(x,y)-L(x,y)\over||(x,y)-(a,b)||}=0$$

For the function $f(x,y)=y^3/(x^2+y^2)$ and $(a,b)=(0,0)$, polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ gives

$${f(x,y)-L(x,y)\over||(x,y)-(a,b)||}={r\sin^3\theta-cr\cos\theta-dr\sin\theta-e\over r}=\sin^3\theta-c\cos\theta-d\sin\theta-{e\over r}$$

We can get a limit as $r\to0$ by setting $e=0$, but there is no trigonometric identity of the form $\sin^3\theta=c\cos\theta+d\sin\theta$, so the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is not only not $0$, it doesn't exist.

Remark: It's not strictly necessary to do so here, but it might help to keep in mind that the choice of $\theta$ can itself vary with $r$, writing it as $\theta_r$ or $\theta(r)$.  Doing so helps emphasize that the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments too long to be put in the comment section.

**1:** Quote from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions): However, the existence of the partial derivatives (or even of all the directional derivatives) does not in general guarantee that a function is differentiable at a point.

**2:** In your case $f_y(0,0) = 1$, not $-2$.

**3:** Just because the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(0,0)$, [does not mean](https://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives) $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. You can use the definition of differentiability to prove it. You can follow [this example](https://youtu.be/JP2KnIj1yXU?t=653).

Comment: to 3.: If already the partial derivatives are not continuous at a point, how shall the function be differentiable at this point? And at least my understanding of differentiability is that if all the partial derivatives of a function $\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous at a point P, then the function is differentiable in P.

Comment: @mathse [Here](https://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives)'s an example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I don't see in this example: The partial derivative of f at (0,0) exists, but in my understanding it is not continuous. If I use polar coordinates in the fashion as in my comment here (computing $\nabla f$, transform it to polar coordinates and let $r \rightarrow 0$) to verify that e.g. $f_x$ is continuous around (0,0) I get an unbounded expression - or am I wrong here?

Comment: @mathse Yes it's a good way to check the partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the partial derivatives are not continuous:
$$
\nabla f =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2 x y^{3} }{(x^{2} + y^{2})^2} \\
\frac{3 x^2 y^2 -y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We convert this into polar coordinates:

$$
\nabla f =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \cos{\alpha} \sin{\alpha}^3 \\
\sin{\alpha}^2 (\cos{2 \alpha}+2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

You see that both components depend on the angle, so the partial derivatives are not steady and the function is not differentiable in $(0, 0)^\top$.

Comment: I understand what you mean by the transformation into polar coordinates and can also reproduce your final result. But why you can conclude, that the components are not steady when they depend on angle? At the moment I cannot see this...Give me a hint please.

Comment: You want to check that the partial derivatives are continuous in $(0, 0)^\top$. So we transform the gradient into polar coordinates and let $r \rightarrow 0$. and the result should be our constant limit value. Since our result does not depend on $r$, we can omit the limit $r \rightarrow 0$, but the result nevertheless should be a fixed value, if the function is continuous. Since the value depends on the angle, it is different, depending on the direction from which you come - so the result depends on the direction so it is not continuous.

Comment: yes - clear now